# Moq: multiple tests through params, one test method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Years ago there was, If I am not mistaken was to have one test method and take parameters in through the method, and these params would be setup with Moq and each diff set of params would create a new test

I cant remember what it was called and I have been searching for a while to find it but cant seem to find it
I simple want to do

```
Moq("john", "mike", "sheila")
Moq("jake", "bleh", "donny")
....
[Test]
public void Test(param1, param2, param2)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: You are referring to parameterised tests and I do not think it is directly related to Moq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) is mocking framework for .NET.

This functionality is not related to Moq, it depends of  unit testing tool. So,
if you're using [xUnit](https://xunit.github.io/) then

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("john", "mike", "sheila")]
[InlineData("jake", "bleh", "donny")]
public void Test(string param1, string param2, string param3)
{
}
```

If you are using MSTest then add the packages [MsTest.TestAdapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestAdapter/) and [MsTest.TestFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestFramework/)

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("john", "mike", "sheila")]
[DataRow("jake", "bleh", "donny")]
public void Test(string param1, string param2, string param3)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this directly with NUnit, using `TestCase` to have parameterized tests:

```
[TestCase("john", "mike", "Sheila")]
[TestCase("jake", "bleh", "donny")]
public void Test(string param1, string param2, string param3)
{
//...
}
```